# How to split a string in shell and get the last field

Tags: bash, split, tokenize, cut

Suppose I have the string `1:2:3:4:5` and I want to get its last field (`5` in this case). How do I do that using Bash? I tried `cut`, but I don't know how to specify the last field with `-f`.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

You can use [string operators](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919):

```
$ foo=1:2:3:4:5
$ echo ${foo##*:}
5
```

This trims everything from the front until a ':', greedily.

```
${foo  <-- from variable foo
  ##   <-- greedy front trim
  *    <-- matches anything
  :    <-- until the last ':'
 }
```

Comment: While this is working for the given problem, the answer of William below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3163857/520162) also returns `5` if the string is `1:2:3:4:5:` (while using the string operators yields an empty result). This is especially handy when parsing paths that could contain (or not) a finishing `/` character.

Comment: How would you then do the opposite of this? to echo out '1:2:3:4:'?

Comment: And how does one keep the part before the last separator? Apparently by using `${foo%:*}`. `#` - from beginning; `%` - from end. `#`, `%` - shortest match; `##`, `%%` - longest match.

Comment: If i want to get the last element from path, how should I use it? `echo ${pwd##*/}` does not work.

Comment: @Putnik that command sees `pwd` as a variable. Try `dir=$(pwd); echo ${dir##*/}`. Works for me!

Comment: @Stephen How do I use dot (.) as a delimiter?

Comment: @Stan even shorter is `echo ${$(pwd)##*/}`

Comment: This worked well for getting the name of the file at the end of a URL for me, by replacing `:` with `/`.

Answer (score 413):

Another way is to reverse before and after `cut`:

```
$ echo ab:cd:ef | rev | cut -d: -f1 | rev
ef
```

This makes it very easy to get the last but one field, or any range of fields numbered from the end.

Comment: This answer is nice because it uses 'cut', which the author is (presumably) already familiar. Plus, I like this answer because *I* am using 'cut' and had this exact question, hence finding this thread via search.

Comment: Some cut-and-paste fodder for people using spaces as delimiters: `echo "1 2 3 4" | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev`

Comment: the rev | cut -d -f1 | rev is so clever! Thanks! Helped me a bunch (my use case was rev | -d ' ' -f 2- | rev

Comment: I always forget about `rev`, was just what I needed! `cut -b20- | rev | cut -b10- | rev`

Comment: I ended up with this solution, my attempt o cut file paths with "awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' " broke somewhat for me, as file names including white spaces got also cut apart

Comment: Beware: `rev` is not safe with multi-byte Unicode characters! Therefore some corner cases might not work with `rev`.

Comment: @t0r0X: Are you sure? On my machine, with `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8`, running `echo 'hé' | rev` correctly returns `éh`. I have to run `echo 'hé' | LC_ALL=C rev` to get an error: `rev: stdin: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`.

Comment: except that: `-sh: rev: command not found` on my NAS, seems like rev is not so common, otherwise I agree it better answers a question about cut

Comment: Fantastic! I wanted to grab only the top-level and second-level domains from a domain name. With `cut`, I can turn things like www.google.com into google.com!

Comment: If you want to extract the TLD out of a list of domains: `cat  domains.txt | rev | cut -d. -f2 | rev | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`

Comment: This is by far the best answer if you are processing a whole file using cat + grep, thanks a lot for coming up with it!!

Answer (score 116):

It's difficult to get the last field using cut, but here are some solutions in awk and perl

```
echo 1:2:3:4:5 | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
echo 1:2:3:4:5 | perl -F: -wane 'print $F[-1]'
```

Comment: great advantage of this solution over the accepted answer: it also matches paths that contain or do not contain a finishing `/` character: `/a/b/c/d` and `/a/b/c/d/` yield the same result (`d`) when processing `pwd | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'`. The accepted answer results in an empty result in the case of `/a/b/c/d/`

Comment: @eckes In case of AWK solution, on GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release that's not true, as it matters whenever you have trailing slash or not. Simply put AWK will use `/` as delimiter, and if your path is `/my/path/dir/` it will use value after last delimiter, which is simply an empty string. So it's best to avoid trailing slash if you need to do such a thing like I do.

Comment: How would I get the substring UNTIL the last field?

Comment: @blackjacx  There are some quirks, but something like `awk '{$NF=""; print $0}' FS=: OFS=:` often works well enough.

Answer (score 41):

Assuming fairly simple usage (no escaping of the delimiter, for example), you can use grep:

```
$ echo "1:2:3:4:5" | grep -oE "[^:]+$"
5
```

Breakdown - find all the characters not the delimiter ([^:]) at the end of the line ($).  -o only prints the matching part.

Comment: -E means using extended syntax; [^...] means anything but the listed char(s); + one or more such hits (will take the maximum possible length for the pattern; this item is a gnu extension) - for the example the separating char(s) are the colon.

Answer (score 29):

You could try something like this if you want to use `cut`:

```
echo "1:2:3:4:5" | cut -d ":" -f5
```

You can also use `grep` try like this :

```
echo " 1:2:3:4:5" | grep -o '[^:]*$'
```

Comment: Your second command was useful to me. Would you break it down so I can understand it better? Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

One way:

```
var1="1:2:3:4:5"
var2=${var1##*:}
```

Another, using an array:

```
var1="1:2:3:4:5"
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
var2=($var1)
IFS=$saveIFS
var2=${var2[@]: -1}
```

Yet another with an array:

```
var1="1:2:3:4:5"
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
var2=($var1)
IFS=$saveIFS
count=${#var2[@]}
var2=${var2[$count-1]}
```

Using Bash (version >= 3.2) regular expressions:

```
var1="1:2:3:4:5"
[[ $var1 =~ :([^:]*)$ ]]
var2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
$ echo "a b c d e" | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1
e
```

Simply translate the delimiter into a newline and choose the last entry with `tail -1`.

Comment: It will fail if the last item contains a `\n`, but for most cases is the most readable solution.

Answer (score 7):

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo '1:2:3:4:5' | sed 's/.*://' # => 5

$ echo '' | sed 's/.*://' # => (empty)

$ echo ':' | sed 's/.*://' # => (empty)
$ echo ':b' | sed 's/.*://' # => b
$ echo '::c' | sed 's/.*://' # => c

$ echo 'a' | sed 's/.*://' # => a
$ echo 'a:' | sed 's/.*://' # => (empty)
$ echo 'a:b' | sed 's/.*://' # => b
$ echo 'a::c' | sed 's/.*://' # => c
```

Comment: given the output of many utilities is in the form of the original file name followed by colon (:) followed by the utility's output (${path}:${output}), this is incredibly useful for adding your own control character like TAB $'\t' or unit separator $'\037' etc. after that final colon. example for adding a TAB at the final colon of file output:

 file ~/yourPath/* | sed "s/\(.*:\)\(.*\)/\1"$'\t'"\2/"

Answer (score 5):

There are many good answers here, but still I want to share this one using **basename** :

```
 basename $(echo "a:b:c:d:e" | tr ':' '/')
```

However it **will fail if there are already some '/' in your string**. 
If slash / is your delimiter then you just have to (and should) use basename.

It's not the best answer but it just shows how you can be creative using bash commands.

Answer (score 4):

If your last field is a single character, you could do this:

```
a="1:2:3:4:5"

echo ${a: -1}
echo ${a:(-1)}
```

Check [string manipulation in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: This doesn't work: it gives the last _character_ of `a`, not the last _field_.

Comment: True, that's the idea, if you know the length of the last field it's good. If not you have to use something else...

Answer (score 2):

Using Bash.

```
$ var1="1:2:3:4:0"
$ IFS=":"
$ set -- $var1
$ eval echo  \$${#}
0
```

Comment: Could have used `echo ${!#}` instead of `eval echo \$${#}`.

Answer (score 2):

Regex matching in `sed` is greedy (always goes to the last occurrence), which you can use to your advantage here:

```
$ foo=1:2:3:4:5
$ echo ${foo} | sed "s/.*://"
5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "a:b:c:d:e"|xargs -d : -n1|tail -1
```

First use xargs split it using ":",-n1 means every line only have one part.Then,pring the last part.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the read builtin:

```
IFS=':' read -a fields <<< "1:2:3:4:5"
echo "${fields[4]}"
```

Or, to make it more generic:

```
echo "${fields[-1]}" # prints the last item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in `echo $str | tr ";" "\n"`; do echo $x; done
```

Comment: This runs into problems if there is whitespace in any of the fields. Also, it does not directly address the question of retrieving the *last* field.

Answer (score 0):

improving from [@mateusz-piotrowski and @user3133260](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765670/8582041) answer,

```
echo "a:b:c:d::e:: ::" | tr ':' ' ' |  xargs | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -1
```

first, tr ':' ' ' -> replace ':' with whitespace

then, trim with xargs

after that, tr ' ' '\n' -> replace remained whitespace to newline

lastly, tail -1 -> get the last string

Comment: If you want to contribute an answer according to [answer] please [edit] to make that more obvious. You can provide an answer based on an existing answer; giving credit to the exsting answers author is then very appropriate, thanks for doing that. I do however have trouble identifying the answer you are reffering to. Please use the link you get from the "Share" link beneath that answer to add an unambigous link here.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Yunnosch, as i am not a native english speaker, i may make mistakes, for all this time using SO just seeking/reading for answers of questions and not answering questions.

Comment: You only describe the code behaviour on a level which (with some experiece) is clear by the code itself. Please explain what it avhieves, i.e. wha the improvement is.

Comment: sorry, as i am a rather forgetful person.
so, the improvement to what i last remember is, to avoid failing if it has empty value between colon (:) or whitespaces.

Answer (score -2):

For those that comfortable with Python, https://github.com/Russell91/pythonpy is a nice choice to solve this problem.

```
$ echo "a:b:c:d:e" | py -x 'x.split(":")[-1]'
```

From the pythonpy help: `-x  treat each row of stdin as x`.

With that tool, it is easy to write python code that gets applied to the input.

**Edit** (Dec 2020):
Pythonpy is no longer online.
Here is an alternative:

```
$ echo "a:b:c:d:e" | python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read().split(":")[-1])'
```

it contains more boilerplate code (i.e. `sys.stdout.read/write`) but requires only std libraries from python.