# How to split a string in bash delimited by tab

Tags: bash, split

I'm trying to split a tab delimitted field in bash.

I am aware of this answer: [how to split a string in shell and get the last field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162385/how-to-split-a-string-in-shell-and-get-the-last-field)

But that does not answer for a tab character.

I want to do get the part of a string before the tab character, so I'm doing this:

```
x=`head -1 my-file.txt`
echo ${x%\t*}
```

But the \t is matching on the letter 't' and not on a tab.  What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you're making a handy one-liner right on the command line, you can press Ctrl+V, then TAB to insert a TAB char.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If your file look something like this (with tab as separator):

```
1st-field   2nd-field
```

you can use `cut` to extract the first field (operates on tab by default):

```
$ cut -f1 input
1st-field
```

If you're using `awk`, there is no need to use `tail` to get the last line, changing the input to:

```
1:1st-field     2nd-field
2:1st-field     2nd-field
3:1st-field     2nd-field
4:1st-field     2nd-field
5:1st-field     2nd-field
6:1st-field     2nd-field
7:1st-field     2nd-field
8:1st-field     2nd-field
9:1st-field     2nd-field
10:1st-field    2nd-field
```

Solution using awk:

```
$ awk 'END {print $1}' input
10:1st-field
```

Pure bash-solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read a b;do last=$a; done < input
echo $last
```

outputs:

```
$ ./tab.sh 
10:1st-field
```

Lastly, a solution using `sed`

```
$ sed '$s/\(^[^\t]*\).*$/\1/' input
10:1st-field
```

here, `$` is the range operator; i.e. operate on the last line only.

For your original question, use a literal tab, i.e.

```
x="1st-field    2nd-field"
echo ${x%   *}
```

outputs:

```
1st-field
```

Answer (score 19):

Use [`$'ANSI-C'` strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in the parameter expansion:

```
$ x=$'abc\tdef\tghi'
$ echo "$s"
abc     def     ghi
$ echo ">>${x%%$'\t'*}<<"
>>abc<<
```

Comment: To me, this solution, using `$'\t'` within the `{}` parameter expansion, fits what the OP was asking. I used this to speed up a script of mine by 76% over using multiple pipes to `cut`.

Answer (score 10):

Use awk.

```
echo $yourfield | awk '{print $1}'
```

or, in your case, for the first field from the the last line of a file

```
tail yourfile | awk '{x=$1}END{print x}'
```

Comment: Thanks - that was it, with one correction: awk -F"\t" '{x=$1}END{print x}'

Comment: Default awk field seperator is whitespace, which includes tab - but maybe your application needed to narrow it.

Answer (score 10):

```
read field1 field2 <<< ${tabDelimitedField}
```

or

```
read field1 field2 <<< $(command_producing_tab_delimited_output)
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation, in order to reduce the impression that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Comment: While being elegant, this seems to split by any whitespace, space or tabs. To split by tab only, use `IFS=$'\t'` before the command.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy way for a tab separated string : convert it to an array.

Create a string with tabs ($ added before for '\t' interpretation) :

```
AAA=$'ABC\tDEF\tGHI'
```

Split the string as an array using parenthesis :

```
BBB=($AAA)
```

Get access to any element :

```
echo ${BBB[0]}
ABC
echo ${BBB[1]}
DEF
echo ${BBB[2]}
GHI
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if items can be zero-length strings, for example `AAA=$'a\t\tc'`

Comment: Bad news indeed ! :-(  Thanks for notifying.  But so far I was lucky, it worked for my scripts.

Comment: It splits the string but it leaves `\t` in ${BBB[0]}

Comment: This seems to split on all whitespace, not just tabs unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

```
x=first$'\t'second
echo "${x%$'\t'*}"
```

See **QUOTING** in `man bash`

Comment: And to only get "second" use: `echo "${x#*$'\t'}"`. See Parameter Expansion in `man bash`

Answer (score 0):

The answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf hints at the use of built in field parsing in bash, but does not really complete the answer. The use of the IFS shell parameter to set the input field separate will complete the picture and give the ability to parse files which are tab-delimited, of a fixed number of fields, in pure bash.

```
echo -e "a\tb\tc\nd\te\tf" > myfile
while IFS='<literaltab>' read f1 f2 f3;do echo "$f1 = $f2 + $f3"; done < myfile

a = b + c
d = e + f
```

Where, of course,  is replaced by a real tab, not \t. Often, Control-V Tab does this in a terminal.