# increment bash variable when piping to function

Tags: bash, pipe, increment

I'm trying to do the following:

```
function func() # in practice: logs the output of a code block to a file
{
    if [ -z "$c" ]; then
        c=1
    else
        (( ++c ))
    fi
    tee -a /dev/null
    echo "#$c"
}

{
echo -n "test"
} | func

{
echo -n "test"
} | func
```

But the increment doesn't work, the variable `c` stays '1'.
I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255303/bash-piping-prevents-global-variable-assignment), but it doesn't work for my case - when I try it, a syntax error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654849/how-to-split-a-string-in-bash-delimited-by-tab) works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
function func() # in practice: logs the output of a code block to a file
{
    if [ -z "$c" ]; then
        c=1
    else
        (( ++c ))
    fi
    tee -a /dev/null
    echo "#$c"
}

func < <(echo -n "test")
func < <(echo -n "test again")
```

this prints:

```
test#1
test again#2
```

Are you using `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang?  If you use `#!/bin/sh`, some bash extensions (such as `<( )`) won't be available.

Comment: What should I do if I need variable assignments in processes of both sides of a pipe?

Comment: Short answer: you can't, although there are other ways.  Bash doesn't do multithreading, so each side of the pipe must run in a separate process, and separate processes can't set each others' shell variables.  A couple of workarounds: First, rather than using a pipe, you could run one function with output redirected to a temporary file; then run the other with input redirected from the file.  Second, let one of the functions run as a subshell, and have it store the relevant value(s) into a temp file; then read that and assign it to variables in the main shell.