# how to split string by tab in bash

Tags: shell, cut

```
test1="one  two three   four    five"
echo $test1 | cut -d $'\t' -f2
```

I have a string which separated by `TAB`, and I want to get the second word by `cut` command.

I've found the question [How to split a string in bash delimited by tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654849/how-to-split-a-string-in-bash-delimited-by-tab). But the solution is not used with `cut`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you need to quote `$test1` when you `echo`:

```
echo "$test1" | cut -d$'\t' -f2
```

Otherwise, the format is gone and the tabs converted into spaces:

```
$ s="hello      bye     ciao"
$ echo "$s"              <--- quoting
hello   bye ciao
$ echo $s                <--- without quotes
hello bye ciao
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `cut` and can save yourself a fork:

```
$ test1=$(printf "one\ttwo\three\tfour\tfive")
$ read _ two _ <<< "${test1}"
$ echo "${two}"
two
```

Comment: `test1="one  two three   four    five"` from the OP was good enough to define the variable, no need to `printf`. Also, the `{}` in `"${test1}` are not necessary in this case.

Comment: It depends on IFS properly set for tabs so if you changed that previously to e.g. break newlines you should set it again, i.e `IFS=$'\t' read ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cut` without any `-d` option:

```
echo "$test1" | cut -f2
```

Below is expert from `cut` man page:

```
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
    use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
```

Comment: actually I've tried this and the result is also the whole test1 string.

Comment: Check the edited post. I have enclosed `$test1` within double quotes.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $test1` by itself? I see no tabs in the output string...  I'd rather use `t="one\tthwo\tthree";echo -e $t|cut -f2` or even `t="one\tthwo\tthree";printf $t|cut -f2`.  Ciao

Comment: @gboffi the problem is in the quotes itself. Once you do not use them in `echo`, the format is lost.

Comment: @fedorqui - sorry but i did not notice your answer. i just tested my code and update.

Answer (score -3):

I run this:

```
test1="one;two;three;four;five"

echo $test1 | cut -d \; -f2
```

and get:

```
two
```

and your example:

```
test1="one  two three   four    five"

echo $test1 | cut -d \t -f2
```

and get:

```
wo
```

Hope that helpful.

---

It's the problem of \t I think.

Comment: You set the delimiter to be a 't' (escaping it had no effect). Based on that the second field is indeed 'wo '.