# Using sed captured group variable as input for bash command

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, sed

I have text like:
`TEXT="I need to replace the hostname [[google.com]] with it's ip in side the text"`

Is there a way to use something like below, but working?
`` sed -Ee "s/\[\[(.*)\]\]/`host -t A \1 | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev`/g" <<< $TEXT ``

looks like the value of **\1** is not being passed to the shell command used inside sed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backquote interpolation is performed by the *shell,* not by `sed`. This means that your backquotes will either be replaced by the output of a command before the sed command is run, or (if you correctly quote them) they will not be replaced at all, and `sed` will see the backquotes.

You appear to be trying to have sed perform a replacement, then have the shell perform backquote interpolation.

You can get the backquotes past the shell by quoting them properly:

```
$ echo "" | sed -e 's/^/`hostname`/'
`hostname`
```

However, in that case you will have to use the resulting string in a shell command line to cause backquote interpolation again.

Depending on how you feel about awk, perl, or python, I'd suggest you use one of them to do this job in a single pass. Alternatively, you could make a first pass extracting the hostnames into a command without backquotes, then execute the commands to get the IP addresses you want, then replace them in another pass.

Answer (score 1):

It's got to be a two part command, one to get a variable that bash can use, the other to do a straight-up /s/ replacement with sed.

```
TEXT="I need to replace the hostname [[google.com]] with it's ip in side the text"
DOMAIN=$(echo $TEXT | sed -e 's/^.*\[\[//' -e 's/\]\].*$//')
echo $TEXT | sed -e 's/\[\[.*\]\]/'$(host -tA $DOMAIN | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev)'/'
```

But, more cleanly using [how to split a string in shell and get the last field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162385/how-to-split-a-string-in-shell-and-get-the-last-field)

```
TEXT="I need to replace the hostname [[google.com]] with it's ip in side the text"
DOMAIN=$(echo $TEXT | sed -e 's/^.*\[\[//' -e 's/\]\].*$//')
HOSTLOOKUP=$(host -tA $DOMAIN)
echo $TEXT | sed -e 's/\[\[.*\]\]/'${HOSTLOOKUP##* }/
```

The short version is that you can't mix sed and bash the way you're expecting to.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

txt="I need to replace the hostname [[google.com]] with it's ip in side the text"
host_name=$(sed -E 's/^[^[]*\[\[//; s/^(.*)\]\].*$/\1/' <<<"$txt")
ip_addr=$(host -tA "$host_name" | sed -E 's/.* ([0-9.]*)$/\1/')
echo "$txt" | sed -E 's/\[\[.*\]\]/'"$ip_addr/"

# I need to replace the hostname 172.217.4.174 with it's ip in side the text
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

I made the below solution:

```
function host_to_ip () {
    echo $(host -t A $1 | head -n 1 | rev | cut -d" " -f1  | rev)
}

function resolve_hosts () {
    local host_placeholders=$(grep -o -e "##.*##" $1)

    for HOST in ${host_placeholders[@]}
    do
        sed -i -e "s/$HOST/$(host_to_ip $(sed -Ee 's/##(.*)##/\1/g' <<< $HOST))/g" $1 
    done
 }
```

Where resolve_hosts gets a text file as an argument