# remove file name in a file path

Tags: linux, unix

I want to extract the only path to the file from a full path.

`for %a in (/path/to/file/filename.txt) do echo %%~dpa`

example:

`/some/path/to/file/filename.txt`

I want to get the only path like

`/some/path/to/file/`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do the trick for you:

```
x=/path/to/file/filename.txt

y=${x%\/*}

echo $y
```

you should get

/path/to/file

Answer (score 0):

You can use string operations to parse the `file_name` out (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162500).

Delete the shortest matching `file_name` from the end of `full_path` using `%` operator.

```
full_path=/path/to/file/filename.txt
file_name=${full_path##*/}
echo "${full_path%$file_name}"
```

Replace `full_path` with your desired input and it will return `/path/to/file/`