# Reformatting ssh-key to import into gcp project metadata

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, ssh, echo, cat

I want to add an ssh-key generated in a shell script to my gcp project metadata. The problem is, that I don't really know how to format the generated key to be in the format which is need for the project metadata. The ssh-key I have looks like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3.... username
```

The format that is stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#add_ssh_keys_to_project_metadata) is this:

```
username:ssh-rsa AAAAB3....
```

Is there a way to reformat the key within my shell script using echo and cat?

My best try is this: `echo $USERNAME:$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)`, but this still leaves the trailing username at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash, this should do the trick:

```
# Use the following line to read the key from a file
# KEY_WITH_USERNAME=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

KEY_WITH_USERNAME="ssh-rsa AAAAB3.... username"
USERNAME=${KEY_WITH_USERNAME##* }

KEY_WITHOUT_USERNAME=${KEY_WITH_USERNAME%"$USERNAME"}

echo $USERNAME:$KEY_WITHOUT_USERNAME
```

Outputs:

```
username:ssh-rsa AAAAB3....
```

See related questions about [how to remove pre- or suffix from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16623897/4564724) and [how to split a string and get the final part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3162500/4564724).

Comment: Small followup question: why does echoing this: `echo $USERNAME:$KEY_WITHOUT_USERNAME > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into a new file not work? It only take the ":".

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it. Forgot to rename the variables.